# how can I create a write-once column in MongoDB to make it tamper proof?

Tags: mongodb, security, readonly

I am using MongoDB. I have an integer attribute in a document that should never be modifiable by anybody with any level of permission. It is ok to delete the document completely, but not modify the field. How to achieve that? Or should I need to switch to in-memory db to achieve this level of security?

Comment: Mongo is a document oriented database, therefore there are no columns. For that reason I doubt that you can configure MongoDB the way you want.

Comment: then we could keep such RO columns in-memory and fetch from there to serve incoming REST calls to the server. Persistence of these RO columns couls be achieved by using an in-memory db's mechanism or ad-hoc persistence, I guess.

Comment: There is no way to configure MongoDB to do this. Your only "in-Mongo" option is probably to add a 'salt' and a 'signature' field and use encryption to sign the document (or at least, the ObjectId and that integer field) so you can tell if that field has been tampered with, but even that's not very secure as someone could copy fields from other records into a known one with the desired value and signature.